# Problem escaping string

Tags: asp.net

```
const string postdescWithComments = @"<span class=""footerLeft"">posted on <a href=""{0}"" title = ""Permanent link to this post"">{1}</a></span><span class=""footerRight""><a href=""{2}#feedback"" title=""comments, pingbacks, trackbacks"" class=""comments""><img class=""feedbackimage"" src=""/skins/xxx/images/cloud.gif"" width=""13"" height=""12"" border=""0"" />Comments({3})</a><a href=""{0}"" class=""moreimage"" title = ""Permanent link to this post""><img src="" 
+ <%=WebUtilityMethods.GetRoot()%> + 
""skins/xxx/images/document.gif border=""0""> More</a></span>";
```

I can't seem to escape this correctly and it's driving me nuts.

`GetRoot()` just returns a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find it easier to follow using String.Format. Try this:

```
String.Format("<img src=\"{0}skins/xxx/images/document.gif\" border=\"0\">", WebUtilityMethods.GetRoot());
```

Comment: sorry I changed up the original post

Comment: yea that's actually how it's setup, duh.  I didn't realize.  It was done further down in code...I usually do it this way but was just running like a mad man today.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you trying to escape it? That code should run inside ASP.NET using declarative syntax, you shouldn't need to escape anything, or perhaps I'm missing something? Try this:

```
<img src=' 
    <%=WebUtilityMethods.GetRoot() + 
    "skins/xxx/images/document.gif"  %>'
    border="0">
```

EDIT: that was the original question. Here's for the new challenge (question was completely changed). It did not contain any errors, but it was hard to read with all the `""` so I replaced it. Not sure what you're after, seems to me that you are trying to use interpreted declarative syntax inside your code behind, which is not possible, sorry:

```
// slightly more readable:
const string postdescWithComments =
                @"
<span class='footerLeft'>
    posted on <a href='{0}' title = 'Permanent link to this post'>{1}</a>
</span>
<span class='footerRight'>
    <a href='{2}#feedback' 
        title='comments, pingbacks, trackbacks' 
        class='comments'>

        <img class='feedbackimage' 
            src='/skins/pmall/images/cloud.gif' width='13' 
            height='12' border='0' />

        Comments({3})
    </a>

    <a href='{0}' class='moreimage' title = 'Permanent link to this post'>
        <img src='{4}skins/xxx/images/document.gif' border='0'>
        More
    </a>
</span>";

// somewhere else, this is where your GetRoot() goes:
string parsedString = String.Format(
     postdescWithComments, 
     href, 
     hrefText,
     hrefFeedback, 
     feedbackText,
     WebUtilityMethods.GetRoot());
```

EDIT: as you've found out, it is very hard to check code like that (esp. when it is on one string as in your original post) for errors. If possible, move the code to the declarative section (the part where the HTML of your page is) Then you can use the `<%=` syntax and as a bonus you get an automatic syntax-check on the HTML.

If that's not possible, you should replace the `<%=...%>` part with a `{4}` and use String.Format to fill in the blanks, the same way you did with the other parts.

EDIT: this last remark, and the ***well-spotted (!)*** closing quote from Agent_9191 have been reflected in the code block for clarity.

Comment: He said GetRoot() returns a string. So the ToString() is pointless.

Comment: He said "`GetRoot()` just returns a string", which I understood as it "returns" *"<%=WebUtilityMethods.GetRoot()%>"*, which is correct looking at his code: it is *not interpreted*. The problem with this code is: it's not on the right spot, hence `GetRoot()` is never executed. But you're right, it is probably a method that returns a string if it were executed ;-)

Comment: sh** can you remove the p*** I dno't want that posted.

Comment: You want to remove what? FYI: you can edit your questions, so you can remove anything you like. Remember you're on a public forum. Anything written here is visible to everyone. Even if you change it, it will remain visible through the edit-history pages of answers and questions.

Comment: PS: I see that you repeated your comments everywhere. Please refrain from doing so, that doesn't add anything to the discussion. If you have question about how to use the site, go to http://meta.stackoverflow.com. If you want to delete your question, you can vote for deletion. No need to try to try to push people. We live in different time zones and are all volunteers.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers were close in stating it's easier to escape your Image tag, but really you were missing a closing quote for the source.  It's also easier to nest altering quotes rather than trying to escape quotes.  Try this:

```
const string postdescWithComments = @"<span class='footerLeft'>posted on <a href='{0}' title='Permanent link to this post'>{1}</a></span><span class='footerRight'><a href='{2}#feedback' title='comments, pingbacks, trackbacks' class='comments'><img class='feedbackimage' src='/skins/xxx/images/cloud.gif' width='13' height='12' border='0' />Comments({3})</a><a href='{0}' class='moreimage' title = 'Permanent link to this post'><img src='"" + <%=WebUtilityMethods.GetRoot()%> + ""skins/xxx/images/document.gif' border='0' /> More</a></span>";
```